# Kafka Streams application issues with version 0.10.2.0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I had an existing Kafka Streams application which was working fine with 0.10.1.1. Updated to the new 0.10.2.0 Kafka Streams library along with the new broker as well (although the new library is backward compatible with 0.10.1.1). Quick background

- I have a REST API built on top of the interactive query metadata based API
- It searches the local store and also queries remote store (using the StreamsMetadata obtained by KafkaStreams.allMetadataForStore method)
- Use the application.server config param in order for this to work

Application is working fine with a single application instance. As soon as I start another instance and query the store via the REST, I experience the following issues

If I execute the search on the node which started first, the local store search failed with this exception

```
SEVERE: Error - the state store, my-store, may have migrated to another instance.
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: the state store, in-memory-avg-store, may have migrated to another instance.
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.StreamThreadStateStoreProvider.stores(StreamThreadStateStoreProvider.java:49)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.QueryableStoreProvider.getStore(QueryableStoreProvider.java:55)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams.store(KafkaStreams.java:699)
        **at mycode.getLocalMetrics(myclass.java:121)**
        **at mycode.remote(myclass.java:98)**
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

If I execute the search on the new node, the local store search was fine, but I see a nullpointer in the **.forEach(new Consumer()** line

```
ks.allMetadataForStore(storeName)
                    .stream()
                    .filter(sm -> !(sm.host().equals(thisInstance.host()) && sm.port() == thisInstance.port())) //only query remote node stores
                    .forEach(new Consumer<StreamsMetadata>() {
                        @Override
                        public void accept(StreamsMetadata t) {
                            //some logic
                        }

                    });
```

What could I be missing ??

Comment: FYI: See the FAQ entry at http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#handling-invalidstatestoreexception-the-state-store-may-have-migrated-to-another-instance for more details plus infos how to address the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to add a little 'sleep-time' for the creatation of StreamsMetadata.When i comment out the `Thread.sleep(1000L);`,i have the same error.

```
    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, props);
    streams.start();

    Thread.sleep(1000L);//If commented out,error occur 
    System.out.println(streams.allMetadataForStore("statestore").size());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you start multiple instances, store might migrate from one instance to another. If you collect the metadata about store location before a store migrates, you metadata is not correct anymore. Thus, you need to refresh your metadata (ie, collect it again).

The exception `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.InvalidStateStoreException: the state store, in-memory-avg-store, may have migrated to another instance` indicates that your meta data is stall.

So you can catch this exception  and retry to recover from it.

Comment: Yes. I have seen this before and I know that this happens during the store migration. But the point is that with 0.10.2.0, this migration seems to be never ending i.e. the as soon as the second node starts, the application goes into this state. Also, as I mentioned, everything works fine with v 0.10.1.1 - no code changes what so ever. That's precisely why I am a bit perplexed.

Comment: What do the logs from the instances tell you? Is the app rebalancing?

Comment: Can you use `KafkaStreams.state()` to see if rebalance finishes and in what state both your apps are when you try to query?

Answer (score 0):

Based on `Matthias J. Sax` comments, one can load stream store inside stream statelistener like below

```
streams.setStateListener((newState, oldState) -> {
   if (newState == State.RUNNING && oldState.REBALNCING) {
      System.out.println(streams.allMetadataForStore("statestore").size());
   }});
```